# Conversion of roll, pitch and yaw from ENU to NED

Tags: imu, gps, pose, first-robotics, coordinate-system

I have roll, pitch and yaw values in an ENU frame.

How can I convert it into a NED frame?

Answer (score 2):

ENU = East, North, Up

NED = North, East, Down

So, if you have `x_ENU`, `y_ENU`, and `z_ENU`, then:

```
x_NED = y_ENU;
y_NED = x_ENU;
z_NED = (-z_ENU);
```

This is like saying `North = North`, `East = East`, and `Down = (-Up)`